# copying after a line has been found from a file from that position till the end of that file in c++

Tags: c++, string, file, copy

I have a file which holds protein coordinates as well as other information preceding it. My aim is to look for a certain line called "$PARAMETERS" and then copy from there every line succeeding it till the end of the file.

How can I get that done? This is the small code I wrote part of the entire program (that someone else wrote years ago, and I took over to upgrade his code for my research):

```
ifstream InFile;
InFile.open (DC_InFile.c_str(), ios::in);

while ( not InFile.eof() )
{
    Line = NextLine (&InFile);

    if (Line.find ("#") == 0) continue;   // skip lines starting with # (comments)
    if (Line.length()   == 0) continue;   // skip empty lines
    size_t pos = Line.find("$PARAMETERS");
    Line.copy(Line.begin("$PARAMETERS")+pos, Line.end("$END"));
    &Line.copy >> x_1 >> y_2 >> z_3;

}
```

Bearing in mind that I defined Line as `string`

Comment: [`while (!.eof())` is almost always wrong](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5). Could you format your post properly, please? What's the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to read data between `$PARAMETERS` and `$END`, not from `$PARAMETERS` until end of file. If so, you can use the following code:

```
string str;
while (getline(InFile, str))
{
    if (str.find("#") == 0)
        continue;
    if (str.length() == 0)
        continue;
    if (str.find("$PARAMETERS") == 0)
    {
        double x_1, y_2, z_3; // you want to read numbers, i guess
        while (getline(InFile, str))
        {
            if (str.find("$END") == 0)
                break;
            stringstream stream(str);
            if (stream >> x_1 >> y_2 >> z_3)
            {
                // Do whatever you want with x_1, y_2 and z_3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will handle multiple sections of data; not sure if you really want this behavior.

For example:

```
# comment
$PARAMETERS
1 2 3
4 5 6
$END
#unrelated data
100 200 300
$PARAMETERS
7 8 9
10 11 12
$END
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely did it for me! Thanks to everyone else who tried to help too. I took your ideas in mind, ran into a few problems but this one worked flawlessly. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want on the first line of the copied file but assuming you get that straight and you haven't read beyond the current line, you can copy the tail of the fike you are reading like this:

```
out << InFile.rdbuf();
```

Here `out` is the `std::ostream` you want to send the data to.

Note, that you should **not** use `InFile.eof()` to determine whether there is more data! Instead, you should read what you want to read and *then* check that the read was successful. You need to check after reading because the stream cannot know what you are trying to read before you have done so.

Comment: Yea I understand, I also forgot to mention that after the $PARAMETERS line, there are X, Y, Z coordinates (written as columns). Therefore, I want to transfer those into 3 different arrays to perform a certain loop. Can that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Dietmar's answer: it sounds to me like you 
should be using `std::getline` until you find a line which
matches your pattern.  If you want that line as part of your
output, then output it, then use Dietmar's solution to copy the
rest of the file.  Something like:

```
while ( std::getline( in, line ) && ! isStartLine( line ) ) {
}
if ( in ) {         //  Since you might not have found the line
    out << line << '\n';    //  If you want the matching line
                            //  You can also edit it here.
    out << in.rdbuf();
}
```

And don't put all sorts of complicated parsing information,
with `continue` and `break`, in the loop.  The results are both
unreadable and unmaintainable.  Factor it out into a simple
function, as above: you'll also have a better chance of getting
it right.  (In your case, should you match `"$PARAMETERS #
xxx"`, or not?)  In a separate function, it's much easier to get
it right.